# List all questions that I edited and answered

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress, edit-and-answer-badges

To get the Illuminator badge, you need to: **Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)**.

How can I list the questions that I already edited and answered?

For example:

[image]

This shows me just the **number**, but I want to list these **9 posts**.

Comment: There is a badge tracker in your profile which will tell you your progress on that badge.

Comment: you can't list your answer, you can find who get this badge, see here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator

Comment: If you go to your profile, you will see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOZAG.png). There is an option to change what badge you're tracking, and it will show your progress.

Comment: Also, why did you reject my edit?

Comment: can you put the link please, i can't see the picture!

Comment: I'm free to accept or to reject your edit, i'm wrong?

Comment: @Mithrandir that's worthy of an answer, IMO.

Comment: Of course it's your choice. I just wanted to know why, since you still have some grammar problems here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OP already had the tracker set to "Illuminator" on SO.

Comment: @S.L.Barth still, it's not common knowledge and since it's not possible to list those questions (without SEDE at least) telling how to see the count is important.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's useful info. I'm just not sure it's what the OP wants to know. LAIDANI Youcef, could you clarify the question please?

Comment: @S.L.Barth I edit my question, you can understand more now

Comment: @LAIDANIYoucef Yes, thank you! Now I understand. This will probably require a SEDE query. (SEDE = Stack Exchange Data Explorer - http://data.stackexchange.com/ ).

Comment: mmm, ok so what is the query then, i think this will help others

Comment: [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507956/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge) is one, but it also lists posts that still have to be upvoted to count for the badge.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/613026/list-all-answers-that-really-count-for-the-illuminator-badge), based on the old one by Martijn Pieters shows all answers which count towards a person's Illuminator badge. (The old query included answers with 0 score as well; those don't count, but might be upvoted in the future – that's probably why they are included. You might be interested in *improving* those answers so that they attract upvotes.)

For reference, here is the complete query:

```sql
select a.Id as [Post Link], a.Score, a.CreationDate
  from Posts q 
  join Posts a on a.ParentId = q.Id
 where q.PostTypeId = 1 and 
       q.ClosedDate is null and
       a.PostTypeId = 2 and 
       a.Score >= 1 and 
       a.OwnerUserId = ##UserId## and
       -- exclude self answered
       IsNull(q.OwnerUserId, -1) <> a.OwnerUserId and 
       exists(select 1 
                from PostHistory ph 
               where ph.PostHistoryTypeId in (4,5) 
                 and ph.PostId = a.ParentId 
                 and ph.UserId = a.OwnerUserId 
                 and abs(datediff(hh, ph.CreationDate, a.CreationDate)) < 12)
order by a.CreationDate desc
```

It comes with the usual disclaimer that SEDE data is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning.

Answer (score 6):

You can find this using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

In fact, someone already created a query for all the answers that qualify:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/507956/list-all-answers-that-count-for-the-illuminator-badge

@Glorfindel correctly observed that this query also counts answers with score 0. Of course, this can easily be solved by changing `a.Score >= 0` to `a.Score > 0`.

For this particular case, listing all answers or listing all questions is almost the same. In fact, listing "all answers" is slightly better since you might just have two answers to the same question.

You can use that query, or modify it to list only the relevant questions.